# Django creates log file but doesn't write into it

Tags: django, logging

I am trying to use Django logger by giving the following settings:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'logfile': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false','require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/tmp/django-log.log',
        'formatter': 'simple'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'user_activity': {
        'handlers': ['logfile',]
    },
}
```

}

and then using it in the view like following:

```
user_logger = logging.getLogger('user_activity')
...
user_logger.info("opened page")
```

Although Django creates file django-log.log, it doesn't write to it. 
Is there a problem with my settings?

Thanks

Comment: do you have write permission in the folder? if you are using ubuntu try using sudo for running

Comment: nope, it's not about permissions. I checked all the permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler filters, you can use either `django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse` or `django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue`, not both. They are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the level of the logging when you create the log object using `logging.getLogger(name)`:

Try this before writing to the logger:

```
user_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```